# Подзапрос из JSON_TABLE в IN клаузе вызывает ошибку: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [qmxptAddDependency1]

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Есть такой JSON в переменной `inc_list`:

```
{"datalist":[
   {
     "idnumber":"123", 
     "value":"Name"   
   },
   {
     "idnumber":"999", 
     "value":"Name1"   
   }]
}
```

Нужно использовать подзапрос в `IN` клаузе. В процедуре делаю следующее:

```
TYPE value_list_type IS TABLE OF varchar2(30);
value_list value_list_type;
[...]            
SELECT VALUE BULK COLLECT INTO VALUE_LIST
FROM TABLE1
WHERE TABLE1.id IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM JSON_TABLE(inc_list, '$.datalist[*]'
        COLUMNS(id VARCHAR2 PATH '$.idnumber'))
);
```

Но это вызывает ошибку:

> ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [qmxptAddDependency1]

Не понимаю, почему. Как ее исправить?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Select from JSON_TABLE in where IN condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65959082) от участника [@SirLancillotto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8933120/sirlancillotto)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65959082

Answer (score 3):

`ORA-00600` это внутреннея ошибка Oracle БД.

Экспериментальным путём на небольшом тестовом примере удалось найти обходное решение. Подсказка `NO_UNNEST` может помешать oптимизатору выполнить некорректную операцию, что, похоже, и является причиной ошибки.

Попробуйте, поможет ли это:

```
declare
    type valuelist is table of varchar2 (30);
    vals valuelist;
    jdoc varchar2 (32767) := '{"datalist":[
        { "idnumber":"3", "value":"Name3" },
        { "idnumber":"9", "value":"Name9" }]}';
begin
    with t (id, value) as (
        select rownum, 'value'||rownum
        from dual connect by level<=9) 
    select value bulk collect into vals
    from t
    where t.id in (
        select /*+ no_unnest*/ id -- <<< FIXME
        from json_table (jdoc, '$.datalist[*]'
            columns (id varchar2 path '$.idnumber')));
    dbms_output.put_line ('result='||vals.count); 
end;
/
```

---

PS ошибка уже известна и для её устранения надо установить патч:

> Bug 24376875 : JSON_TABLE QUERY AS NON-SYS USER ORA-600 [QMXPTADDDEPENDENCY1]

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65961631) от участника [@mathguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5683823/mathguy)</sub>